# CMD to batch duplicate desktop shortcut with arguments (program not installed in same location on all workstations)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, shortcut-file

Need to duplicate a desktop shortcut on the public desktop to include command line arguments as needed for client configurations. Using the CreateShortcut.vbs has been unsuccessful since the program is not installed in same location on every workstation.

Short of uninstalling/reinstalling or generating the shortcuts manually as have been done in the past, I am at a loss.

Help me Obi Wan Kenobi...  you are my only hope....

Comment: SO users can help you debug something, **once you have tried something**.  We will help you, no do it for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Set exepaths=%%ProgramFiles%%,%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%,C:\literal\file\path

for /r %%exepaths%% %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="Program.exe" set p=%%~dpnxa
if defined p (
echo %p%
) else (
echo File not found
)